# How to feed pre-configuration while installing mysql using apt-get

Tags: apt, system-installation, mysql

Installing mysql using below command will prompt to enter password

```
$apt-get install mysql-server
```

Is their is any way to install mysql such that it should't prompt the user to enter password.

One working alternative way I found was:

```
$sudo -E apt-get install mysql-server
```

I am curious to know any other existing ways.

Comment: That password is not for configurning `mysql`

Comment: I am looking for alternative to skip "promoting for password" while installing using apt-get. looking for any configuration before installing or any other ways

Comment: That's impossible

Comment: I have given one alternative way !!

Comment: sudo is used to use admin privileges to install _any package_ using apt-get in your system. It doesnt _pre configure_ anything for mysql in any special way

Comment: @suraj I agree, I don't want it to promt anything for me. as my idea is to use it in script to install along many packages

Comment: It will ask for password even if you use `-E` option

Comment: thats because `-E` sets current user env see [man pages](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.20/sudo.man.html#E)

Comment: @suraj you are right

Comment: @fresher Why reinvent the wheel? Here is a script for an unattended installation of mysql: https://gist.github.com/sheikhwaqas/9088872 It includes also a way yo set up configuration (like timezone, firewall, my.cnf and privileges).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root | debconf-set-selections
```

then install the mysql

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Those echo's need to be between quotes.You should also add the `-y` in `apt-get -y install mysql-server`.  Plus you still need to change `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and set up privileges for this user